# Clone an element into a new window in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an input form, that I want to clone into a new window.  I need to clone it with a deep copy so it will preserve the user inputs from the fields vs. just the "value" tag in html.

```
var printForm = data.clone(false, true);
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can't find a way to write it into the document.  I can use the .html(), but it doesn't preserve the input values, like:

```
newwindow.document.write(printForm.html());
```

This prints the form, but without the new values.  In Firefox/Chrome I write what I need to the document, close it, and use:

```
printForm.appendTo(newwindow.document.body);
```

Unfortunately security in IE doesn't allow you to append from data in a different window.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: take out the values manually, then re-add them ?

Comment: Yes, are you not able to manually get the old and set the new values?

Comment: It's a large dynamic form that I'm copying into a new window to use window.print() with.  The copying of the form works in about 1 line with Chrome/Firefox. So I was tring to figure out if there was a similar solution for IE, aside from specifically pulling each potential value and passing it in with document.write() into a script and manually re-adding them all.